# Trying to make new column of values from second dataframe based on values in two other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I have two dataframes, df1 has columns with month and year associated with the data and df2 has month (in numbers) as the headers and years as the index values.

I'm then trying to populate a new column in df1 with the appropriate values that correspond to the month/year from df2. I have tried .loc function but not sure if it's meant to populate a whole column or just return one value at a time.

df1

| other data | month | year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | 12 | 1966 |
| xyz | 1 | 1997 |

df2

| index | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | .... | 12 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1929 | x | y | z | x | y | .... | z |
| 1930 | x | y | z | x | y | .... | z |
| ... | x | y | z | x | y | .... | z |
| 1966 | x | y | z | x | y | .... | z |
| 1997 | x | y | z | x | y | .... | z |

and I want a new column to be added to df1 like this, based on values from df2:

| other data | month | year | df2_value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xyz | 12 | 1966 | z |
| xyz | 1 | 1997 | x |

so far I have been trying this:

```
df1['df2_value'] = df2.loc[df1['year'],df2['month']]
```

but I'm getting this key error:

```
KeyError: "None of [Int64Index([12,  1,  2,  3,  2,  2,  3,  2,  4,  1,  1,  2,  3,  2,  1,  2,  2,\n
2,  2,  2, 12,  3,  1,  2, 12,  1,  2, 11,  3,  1,  2,  1,  3, 12,\n             
4,  3,  2,  1,  3,  2, 11, 12, 10, 12,  2,  4,  3,  1,  4,  1,  1,\n             
2,  3,  1,  2,  4,  2,  2,  2,  4,  2,  3, 12,  9, 12,  3,  2,  3,\n             
1,  2,  3, 11, 11,  4],\n           dtype='int64')] are in the [columns]"
```

I have changed the month and year columns in df1 to object type instead of integer but that didn't change the error. This is my first time trying to use .loc so could be missing something very obvious or maybe I need to use an entirely different function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just stack df2, reset the index and merge

```
df1.merge(df2.stack().reset_index(),
          left_on=['year', 'month'],
          right_on=['index', 'level_1'])


  other data month  year index level_1  0
0        xyz    12  1966  1966      12  z
1        xyz     1  1997  1997       1  x
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm very new to this so might still be missing something. Now I have a dataframe that has all the correct headers like your example but the dataframe is empty...
I did this:
df1 = df1.merge(df2.stack().reset_index(),
          left_on=['year', 'month'],
          right_on=['index', 'level_1'])

Does that mean that they don't actually match up?

Comment: Is it not working on your sample dataset in this question or on your real-world data? you may need to check the merge fields - i.e., the `left_on` and `right_on` values to make sure they are formatted correctly either as ints or strings. If strings make sure there are no extra spaces that would prevent them from matching.

Comment: played around with the types and got it to match up now, thanks so much!